# Where should i store my Email content in Database or file system?

Tags: sql-server, windows

I'm currently planning a new design of an email storage and delivery system built mostly with a sql server 2012 backend.

Most of the schema is set out for the actual creation of the emails but i'm still not sure on one design element

Where to store the archive of sent emails?

Should i store them in sql database as nvarchar(max)

or actually store them as files within the file system itself (.htm files for example) and then just have a link to the file stored in the database

very much in the same way as i store photos currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advocate using the file system.

I built an email engine years ago that in its' day delivered a million messages per hour (it was a pretty big deal then). While there is value in having traceability through database logging, etc., I found working with file system is significantly easier to manage day to day.

I built out a semi-RESTful structure like so:

- Client (A)

  - Year

    - Month

      - Day

        - Email Subject

          - message.html
          - message.txt

            - Images
            - Etc.

In addition to being a simple file structure, it also makes managing other file dependencies easier.  Emails often include images, file attachments, etc. and keeping a those files bundled within the same *email resource folder* reduced complexity.

My *emails* table still needed a reference to the path of the email but that was easily calculated based on the [scheduled] email delivery date.

To specifically address your SQL Server suggestion I can say I tried storing emails exactly as you suggested as well.  In the end, and for my particular technology stack, I need to write my files to disk for an "online version" anyway.  When you've got dynamic emails being written like this:

*Dear [John Smith],*

*Thank you for your interest in [XYZ]*.

Handling variable substitution is drastically easier when the file is available to be served by your backend (.NET, Java, Rails, etc.) by simply providing an ID.

http://myclient.emailserver.com/2013/10/29/the-most-brilliant-subject-line-ever?id=1234

Last but certainly not least you must weight the additional cost of keeping those emails in your database.  SQL Server is a beautiful piece of software - personally, I think it's the best thing Microsoft ever built - but these emails are archive material and they're just adding bulk to your system.  I don't know the scale of the system you're attempting to build but if even with a hundred million emails (which isn't that hard to produce) you're talking about a *lot* of girth.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: excellent Seth - sounds very much along the lines of what i was lending towards and your post as well as the others above have convinced me

Comment: Storing blobs in the database can actually be faster than storing them on the filesystem depending on the size of the files: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

Comment: @SethMacPherson just out of curiosity, what did you use to safely separate html and text versions of the message and the attachments and do that in a way this html is safe to be exposed as part of your webmail interface (avoiding cross-site scripting attacks)?

Comment: I recently built a system that automatically converts emails from a specific [trusted] sender into the News section of a website and, without better solutions, I had to write my own parser for this stuff. It worked, but I always had this thought of how safe it really was if I was going to do the same for untrusted senders, that could try to insert "ilegal" tags in the message or pass some broken structure that would corrupt the site's layout.

Answer (score 2):

SMTP servers usually already store them as files, in `.eml` format. You can chose to keep them that way and use your database to catalog and index them, or you can store everything in the database, but personally I think its dangerous to do that for some reasons:

1. You database would rapidly increase in size, as a single message can have more then 10MB, and NVARCHAR uses UNICODE, so that would be actually 20MB. Storage-wise it's a highly inefficient solution;
2. No database server handle variable length data very well, you may have performance issues and database files that continuously grow in size even if you delete stuff;
3. Afaik each table has a limit of 8TB, this may be small depeding on your case;
4. A typical backup would generate monstrous files of possibly many terabytes. You would have to create a custom backup solution to manage that;
5. When storing large amounts of data, hard disk errors are to be taken in consideration. If some sector gets corrupted you can lose a random email file, and thats usually okay. If the database file get corrupted it will be a catastrophic problem. A smaller database covers less space in disk and runs less risk of having a sector corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons you don't want to store lots of blobs in sql is that the backups take longer and longer and cannot as easily be split to a seperate file server (or servers) that can run concurrently with your SQL server backup -- this factor alone causes lots of grief when you use SQL as a file store