# Storing e-mails in a SQL database

Tags: sql

I want to create a simple messaging application that stores the messages (similar to e-mails, but simply messages). How should I design the database?

Table `Users`:

- Username (primary key)
- Userpassword

Table `E-mails`:

- EmailID (Primary key)
- From (Foreign key to user)
- To
- Owner (Foreign key to user)
- Subject
- Time
- Email content
- Email layout (Possibly content and layout in one field? XAML)

Since an e-mail can be sent to multiple people, what would be the best way to store the to column? Should I simply put it as a string, separated by commas, then retrieve all the users with a function in my code? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: If all recipients are within the model (so message to outside), then you should store them as a reference table, not inside the message table at all. That way you get around parsing the entry and all addresses are always up to date.

Comment: And a general not, just to make sure you remember that: You should _never_ store a user password inside a database.

Comment: @arkascha I'm supposed to store the password in the database, as hash unfortunatly.

Comment: *Should I simply put it as a string, separated by commas* good heavens **NO!** - there is **always** a better way than this!

Comment: Storing a hash of passwords is perfectly fine. Take care to use a good algorithm though, not just some...

Comment: see also [Where should i store my Email content in Database or file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669067/where-should-i-store-my-email-content-in-database-or-file-system)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Table Users**

- Username (primary key)
- Userpassword

**Table E-mails**

- EmailID (Primary key)
- From (Foreign key to user)
- Subject
- Time
- Email content
- Email layout (Possibly content and layout in one field? XAML)

**Table Email_Recipients**

- Recipient ID (Primary Key)
- RecipientUserID (Foreign key from User Table)
- EmailID (Foreign key from Email Table)
- RecipientType //Types can be Actual, CC, BCC

Another table can be created of **EmailRecipientTypes**

Like
**Table EmailRecipientTypes**

- TypeID (Primary Key)
- TypeName //can be Actual, CC or BCC

In this way you can modify the Table Email_Recipients as

**Table Email_Recipients**

- Recipient ID (Primary Key)
- RecipientUserID (Foreign key from User Table)
- EmailID (Foreign key from Email Table)
- RecipientTypeID (Foreign key from Table EmailRecipientTypes)

Although the fourth table will only contain 3 records but it will help in reducing in the data replication and will help you in grouping emails in some required way that you want (its a maybe)

Comment: Thank you, great answer!

Answer (score 7):

Table Users

- UserId
- Username
- Password

Table Emails

- EmailId
- From (Foreign key to UserId)
- Owner (Foreign key to UserId)
- Subject
- EmailContent
- EmailLayout
- Time

Table Recipients

- Id
- Email (Foreign key to EmailId)
- To (Foreign key to UserId)

So the recipients of the email are linked to the email as a many to one mapping.

This way you can select all the recipients of an email by selecting all the rows in the `Recipients` table with the appropriate `EmailId`

For example an email sent to 2 users will have rows (as an example)

```
---------------------------
| Id  | Email | To        |
---------------------------
| 1   | 1     | 3 (User1) |
---------------------------
| 2   | 1     | 4 (User2) |
```

[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) Gives good examples as to why using comma separated values in a database table is bad practise.